# A modification of integral curves

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, terminology, curves

[Integral curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) are defined in Wikipedia by the formula

$$\mathbf{x}'(t) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}(t)).$$

What about a modified definition such that requires only that the vectors $\mathbf{x}'(t)$ and $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}(t))$ are of the same direction (not necessarily the same length)?

I am almost sure that there is some (widespread) term for such modified definition of integral curves.

(Regular) integral curves for a vector field seem to correspond bijectively
to such modified integral curves for a slope field. I asked about this in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1882515/4876).

Comment: "reparameterized integral curves" perhaps?

Comment: @JohnHughes Is there a straightforward proof that reparametrized integral curves are exactly these which have vectors $\mathbf{x}'(t)$ and $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}(t))$ of the same direction?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I suggested "reparameterized integral curves" as a name for these things. The only question is whether such things really ARE reparameterized integral curves. Here's a quick proof that they are (under very mild constraints):

Suppose that $x'(t) = c(t) F(x(t))$ for some function $c$ that's *everywhere positive*. (I assume that this is included in your notion of "pointing the same direction".

Let

$$y(u(t)) = x(t),$$
where 
$$
u(t) = \int_0^t c(s) ~ds,
$$
which, because $c$ is positive, is a monotone function, and therefore has an inverse defined on its image.

Then 
\begin{align}
y'(u(t)) u'(t) &= x'(t) \\
&= c(t) F'(x(t)) \text{, so}\\
y'(u(t)) c(t) &= c(t) F'(y(u(t))) \\
y'(u(t))  &=  F'(y(u(t)))
\end{align}
and letting $s = u(t)$ we have
$$
y'(s) = F'(y(s)),
$$
(at least for $s$ in the image of $u$)
as needed.

Comment: Why the integral $u(t) = \int_0^t c(s) ~ds$ exists and is finite?

Comment: We can select a $c(t)$ in such a way that it is non-integrable. Probably adding $C^1$-smoothness helps?

Comment: Oh, sure. Let's assume $c$ is smooth enough to be integrable, and is indeed continuous, for if it's not, then you probably get a contradiction in assuming that $x$ is differentiable. And then its integral, on any compact domain, will be finite because of this continuity. (I'm also assuming that $F$ is continuous, and probably Lipschitz or something so that it actually is guaranteed to have integral curves.) I can never remember the requirements on this, but I'm pretty sure that if you're asking questions like this, you can look it up.